# servlet checkbox not grabbing all values

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm trying to finish this servlet that adds a new course to my courses display. I'm using a check box so the user can pick what the prerequisite are for the new course they want to add. so if they check cs201, it will add cs201 as a prerequisite for that new course.

For some reason my checkbox will only add the first checkbox that is clicked. If I add a subject and click the check boxes for cs203, cs202, and cs201 it will only grab cs201 and add it to my course display. It wont grab all 3. How can I grab the other info that's checked?

So then I figured out that I had to change my parameter value into a string. But now I'm stuck on what to do next.

```
String[] prerequisites = request.getParameterValues("prerequisites");
```

I updated my constructor to take in arrays, and I'm using the code below to add

```
entries.add(new Courses (code,title, prerequisites));
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: bah , forget it . i cant get the site to post my code or question right, i appologize

Comment: You can get editing help tips if you click the `?` on the top right corner of the edit box.